# MongoDB get all documents who's subdocuments only contain a specific value?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB, so I may have some terminology wrong, but I don't think I've seen anyone ask a question exactly like this:

If I have a collection of documents that have a shape something like:

```
{
_id: ObjectID('656ce741b78f8f5fea229c4f'),
year: 2,
name: "Student Name",
grades: [
  {
    date: ISODate('2014-08-16T00:00:00.000Z'),
    grade: 'A',
    score: 97
  },
  {
    date: ISODate('2014-03-19T00:00:00.000Z'),
    grade: 'A',
    score: 91
  },
  {
    date: ISODate('2015-08-16T00:00:00.000Z'),
    grade: 'B',
    score: 82
  }
]
}
```

How would I find all of the straight A students? That is, all of the students such that the grades array only contains `grades.grade = "A"`. I can provide the actual document structure, but the logic should be the same for this example collection of imaginary student documents.

I've tried using `$all`, but I think that expects an array of values, not an array of objects. I've also tried `$elemMatch` with `$ne: B` and `$ne: C`, but that seems to return anything where at least one of the elements is an `A`, instead of requiring all elements to be `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should only match documents where all elements of the grades array have a value that is not equal B or C:

`{"grades.grade":{$nin: ["C","B"]}}`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enumerating all the negative possibilities (i.e.the values that you don't want, currently `B` and `C`), you can use `$map` to create a boolean array that check for `grades.grade` equal to A or not. Then, use `$allElementsTrue` on the resulting array to check whether all array entries are A or not. In this way, if you are introducing new negative values like `D` or `E`..., you code is still working as expected.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$allElementsTrue": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$grades",
        "as": "g",
        "in": {
          "$eq": [
            "$$g.grade",
            "A"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zyiua_46Bbw)